# How to add more than one child to a floatingActionButton

Tags: flutter

How can I add more than one child to my `FloatingActionButton`? I want to add some shadow under the button, and the only way I found to do it was by adding a container, but therefore I had to remove my icon child. I am new to flutter and coding in general.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AddTaskPage(),
            ),
          );
        },
        tooltip: 'Add Task',
        
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        //child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
        child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(100),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
              spreadRadius: 7,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(3, 5),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
        
      ),
```

I tried using the Stack function but could not figure it out. Maybe it is my lack of experience; it probably is

Answer (score 2):

use the **Stack** widget to placing both the **Icon** and the **Container** inside it. The Stack widget allows you to overlay widgets on top of each other

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => AddTaskPage(),
      ),
    );
  },
  tooltip: 'Add Task',
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
      Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(100),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
              spreadRadius: 7,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(3, 5),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

If you want to add a shadow to the `FloatingActionButton` itself without affecting its child, you can wrap the `FloatingActionButton` with a `Container` and apply the shadow

```
floatingActionButton: Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
        spreadRadius: 5,
        blurRadius: 7,
        offset: Offset(0, 3),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => AddTaskPage(),
        ),
      );
    },
    tooltip: 'Add Task',
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
  ),
),
```

Comment: this makes it look like the button itself is blurry.

Comment: i update the answer check it

Answer (score 0):

yo make shadow  under the FAB you must be add the property namd elevation and accept a double number like this :

```
    FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => AddTaskPage(),
        ),
      );
    },
    tooltip: 'Add Task',
    // Use elevation to make shadow under the button
    elevation: 20,  
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    // use shape to make the FAB Rounded
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: it does give me a shadow but its black and not blue.